# Save Values AUTOMATICALLY with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I have an app with two UITextFields, where the user enters an integer, and then a method is called with the values the user enters. But when I completely close the app, the values are deleted. I want to change it to save the value the user entered when it closes, and loads it up when the app is re-opened. I tried this with NSUserDefault, and it worked fine (with save and load button), but I want it to make it automatically, without pressing any buttons. I saw some other people do it with the basic methods in the AppDelegate.m, but I don't know anything about that, therefore I didn't understand it at all.

I saw MANY tutorials online, but I didn't understand any of them, please help, and give a detailed answer, thanks :)

Comment: can you put the method that is being called when the values are change by the user?

Answer (score 1):

Keep using `NSUserDefaults`, there's no better approach for what you want to do.

In your case, just set a delegate on the `UITextField`, and every time the value changes, save it in `NSUserDefaults`. In this way, you won't have any buttons and your `NSUserDefaults` will contain always the last value.

Answer (score 1):

You got it working with a Save button right? Then just apply the same code in the text changed event of the UITextField like this:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This means when the text changes in the field the code in 'txtFieldDidChange' will run. This is where you write to NSUSerDefaults

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just define two fonctions, one to save your two strings and another one to load them.

```
    -(void)saveTextFieldValues() {
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        // saving
        [prefs setObject:self.firstTextField.text forKey:@"FirstTextFieldKey"];
        [prefs setObject:self.secondTextField.text forKey:@"SecondTextFieldKey"];

        [prefs synchronize];
     }

-(void)loadTextFieldValues() {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //Load textField texts

    if ([prefs stringForKey:@"FirstTextFieldKey"]):
        self.firstTextField.text = [prefs stringForKey:@"FirstTextFieldKey"];

    if ([prefs stringForKey:@"SecondTextFieldKey"]):
        self.secondTextField.text = [prefs stringForKey:@"SecondTextFieldKey"];

}
```

Then call `saveTextFieldValues` inside your callback (when user change one of the textFields) and call `loadTextFieldValues` just after you create textFields.